# is it possible to toggle notifications?

Tags: android

I have a galaxy tab and in the settings you can turn notifications on or off. But is this something that samsung made rather than google? I ask because I am making app for napping and this would really come in handy.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google made this functionality in Android. And yes you can toggle to have notifications on or off, put the phone or vibrate, or silent.

Check out [Audio Manager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html)